# Launch two camera nodes for stereo calibration

Tags: ros, usb-cam, stereo-calibration, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am attempting to launch two camera nodes via a launch file in order to calibrate them via stereo. Below is my launch file:

```
<launch> 

  <node name="leftCam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>

  <node name="left_image_view0" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/leftCam/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>

  <node name="rightCam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>

  <node name="right_image_view0" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/rightCam/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

I am pretty new to ROS and need some help getting this to output two separate image to my monitor, each from separate cameras.

Right now I run `roscore` in one terminal followed by `roslaunch (launch_file_name).launch` in another terminal. I get two little grey boxes on my screen but no camera output. I have verified that the cameras are connected as they can be accessed via other software.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237397/launch-two-camera-nodes-for-stereo-calibration/) by [Matson](https://answers.ros.org/users/27210/matson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You've probably solved this by now, but i ran into the same problem so thought i'd share the answer.

Basically it's because there isn't enough bandwidth on the the USB.

If you change your resolution to say 320*240 it will work. You can force the camera to calculate the max resolution but i couldn't get that to work.

Hope this helps!

Oh, you've also given bot cameras the same device ID too, set one of them to 1 and the other to 2.

---

Originally posted by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) with karma: 98 on 2018-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0